# Is Mono stable and fast enough for web production?

Tags: linux, .net, mono

I am currently investigating for a new web application stack for my web server.

C# looks great because it is a compiled language which seems to run quite well without too much CPU and does not consume too much memory. And StackOverflow and ServerFault are good examples of an MVC/.Net/C# stack that scales.

C# is also interesting because despite being compiled, it still has a lot of advanced features as a language only found on slower interpreted language.

My server being Linux only (Ubuntu 8.04 LTS), I am wondering if installing Mono in place of the .Net framework is a good idea for production use.

I currently do not have any existing applications using .Net but I am interested in using existing frameworks (like MS MVC).

Comment: Ask this on stackoverflow, for sure.  You'll probably get better detailed answers there for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP MVC is new enough that it [might take a little while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202430/asp-net-mvc-preview-5-on-mono) for things to be ironed out on the Mono implementation.  However for plain old ASP .NET Mono works great for C# or [precompiled](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.4) sites in other languages.

Comment: Here's some guidance for getting ASP.NET MVC going on Mono:
http://beyondfocus.com/mono/asp-net-mvc-on-mono-two-options-for-the-ide-crowd/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually waited for this site to come online to ask this question and never tried to simply search StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 2):

I am currently working with a startup on an SaaS offering wherein one of the "enterprise" grade products is written in C# and the vendor actually stands behind Linux/Mono deployments much more than they do Windows/.NET -- in fact, they say they've never had a truly large-scale Windows deployment, though they started out in Windows & .NET, but they've successfully launched multiple large-scale Linux/Mono deployments of their fairly popular-in-its-space product.

Comment: Interesting. Wonder whether they understand what their 'upgrade path' looks like when they start looking for functions that are in .Net, but not in Mono... But I like this story :-) Shows the power of open source.

Comment: At one point they had features in Windows not available in Linux, but their pledge now is to keep both versions at the same featureset. They do understand, and it was a question we had when talking with them.